# Is there a way to make Python lists require a certain object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched all over the internet but I cannot figure out a way to essentially make a Python list that requires a certain object.

What I want to achieve would be described in C# as: `new List<MyObject>()` which would then create a new list that takes a certain object as an input.

Now I cannot figure out any way whatsoever to achieve this in Python.

I'm trying to define a class of Tides information as such:

```
from models.tideTime import TideTime


class Tides:
    def __init__(self, currentTide: str, movement: str, tideTimes: list):
        self.currentTide = currentTide
        self.movement = movement
        self.tideTimes = tideTimes
```

Where the list in question there should be a list of "TideTime" object, not just any normal list. Where this TideTime object is another class defined in the models directory as:

```
class TideTime:
    def __init__(self, time: str, height: str):
        self.time = time
        self.height = height
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

I know that it does not exactly matter because at the end of the day I can still call it with a list of TideTime objects on the other side but for clean code purposes and longevity I would like to ensure that the list input to this object is always of the correct type and not a `str` all of a sudden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for static typing, but Python is dynamically typed. Trying to fight the language design like this is a bad idea. Don't write C# in Python.

Comment: There's type hinting, but it's not enforced in any way.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/learn-how-to-use-static-type-checking-in-python-3-6-in-10-minutes-12c86d72677b might help

Comment: There's [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) module, but as it said in docs "The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc."

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys. You all make valid points. I guess it makes sense to not force static typing in a language that is not built for it. But the typing module does help make it a little clearer when you are reading the code. That being said perhaps I've just gotten too used to reading other languages (I'm a bit of a python rookie). Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the type hint `List[TideTime]`, where `List` is imported from the `typing` module.

```
from typing import List
from models import TideTime

class Tides:
    def __init__(self, currentTide: str, movement: str, tideTimes: List[TideTime]):
        self.currentTide = currentTide
        self.movement = movement
        self.tideTimes = tideTimes
```

Python itself ignores the type hint, but a tool like `mypy` can help catch if you try to pass something else in your source code. If nothing else, the more accurate hint better documents the *intent* of the function.

Comment: Thanks chepner! That is what I was looking for (there's a little typo still in your answer though, should be `List[TideTime]`, instead of `List[TimeTime]`), thank you so much!

Comment: @Johan: As @chepner mentioned, Python itself ignores type hints at runtime, so doing simple adding them doesn't enforce the restriction. If you want to do that, you'd need to derive a subclass of the built-in `list` class that enforced it at runtime.

Comment: Yeah thanks @martineau, yeah I understand that but at least this way through the use of linters and IDE's if someone else in the future looks at this code and tries to provide it the wrong thing hopefully it'll notify them that "no this expects a list of such and such type".

Comment: @Johan: Well, if that's all you want… Keep in mind that the notion of typing is a little different in Python, and requiring a certain type (or subclass of one) is "unpythonic" — in other words you may be trying to write C# code in Python, which supports the notion of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) so explicit type checking of any kind doesn't necessarily make as much sense.

Comment: @martineau: Yeah I'm aware of this and perhaps I should be attempting to read up more on "pythonic" methods. I'm new to python and slipped into it through a growing interest in computer science and machine learning but my background being C++/C# I guess I'm not used to the ways of writing python.

Would you know any good books that perhaps offers a bit of a crash course in effectively developing in Python? Similar to "Effective Java" perhaps?

I mean a quick google lead me to this: "https://effectivepython.com/", not sure if it's any good and would rather have a recommendation from someone

Comment: @Johan: I, too, had to make a fair number of adjustments coming from a extensive C++ background. Haven't read _Effective Python_, but the list of what it covers looks good. Personally I probabaly learn the most from the _Python Cookbook_ series oublished by O'Reilly. The first two editions were very good, and the 3rd Edition by David Beazley is also excellent. The 2nd Ed doesn't cover Python 3, but is still very relevant so you could save a little money by picking up a used copy of it.

Comment: @martineau: Thanks mate I appreciate the recommendation. I will definitely look into it as I do want to write pythonic code if I'm going to bother writing it at all :) have a good one!